# How to prevent bypassing login.php without including it in every other file?

Tags: php, authentication

I'm trying to secure my website using session variables, and I handle the authentication in login.php. Is there any way to prevent people from bypassing this file and accessing the rest of the directory other than adding an include at the top of every file in the directory?

Sorry if this has been asked before, but when I was researching this almost every answer was to just add includes to every file. This is not an ideal solution because there are a lot of files in this directory, and going through every one would be a bit of a pain.

Basically just asking if there is a way to prevent access to the entire directory and redirect to login.php until it has run. Is there a way to do this with a .htaccess file maybe?

Honestly, I don't know what code to give you guys here, as it's more of a permissions question than a coding issue. If you need something comment and I'll gladly add it in but I don't see how any of my code would be helpful here.

Comment: You don't have to include a file in every file, just check the session.  This would be easier by including a file. Look at `auto-prepend-file` in php.ini or .htaccess.

Comment: In modern PHP, you don't require a single file. You use autoloading, and it loads many files automatically. Usually you have a starting point, say `index.php` and all files are loaded in it. You could check it out, take a look into composer. Now, you can define a constant in one of these files that you always include. There's also prepend files that you can use but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Yes I have a check for you the session variable in index.php, and it works for some of the files, but not every one. Some of them I can still access without going through the login page first.

Comment: @AbraCadaver How do I check the session variable in . htaccess? I thought it executed before the session or something and it didn't have access to session variables?

Comment: You don't you would use it to automatically prepend a PHP file that does the check.

Comment: Ah I see, I didn't quite understand. Thank you, this should work nicely.